# Integration slope problem with $x^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

You are given the function $\int_{0}^{y}x^{x}dx=x^y$. Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$, you get $y=f(x)$. For what value of $x$ is the slope of $f(x)$ lowest?

I found this problem but I don't understand how to solve it. My math knowledge only extends up to Multi. Does it have to do with the Sophomore's Dream or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: I'd rewuite the left side as: $$\int_0^y t^t\,dt.$$ It can be confusing to use $x$ as a variable and $dx$ inside an integral.

Comment: Note the right side depends on $x$ but the left side does not.

Comment: Yes, you can write $x$ in terms of $y:$ $$x=\left(\int_0^y t^t\,dt\right)^{1/y}$$ So you are really looking for an inverse of a function.

Comment: Take derivative of both sides